# Make image go outside of boundaries in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I`m new to compose and am trying to use an `Image()` composable with this specifics:

[image]

The Image needs to have more height and width than it`s parent but from a fixed offset (the green dot).

How can I achieve this design with jetpack compose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume that your Sidebar is a `Column`, then the code would look like this:

```
Sidebar() {
  Column() { 
    TopSidebar() // top part of sidebar, but not fillMaxHeight

    Image(
      modifier = Modifier
        .wrapContentSize(unbounded = true, align = Alignment.TopStart),
      ... rest of parameters
    )
  }
}
```

The key things are `unbounded = true` and `align`. `TopStart` is your case

I wrote more about it with examples [here on Medium](https://medium.com/@iRYO400/how-to-make-an-image-draw-outside-of-its-boundaries-in-jetpack-compose-b72ac8c58fcd)

Comment: If your image is too big, use `contentScale = FixedScale(1f)` on `Image`