# Transparent Background Icon in Compose Extending Beyond Layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to place a background image (or icon) in my Composable. I've tried to find which question is the closest to mine and this one is the best I could find:

[Make image go outside of boundaries in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74665576/make-image-go-outside-of-boundaries-in-jetpack-compose)

This is my current code:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun RecipeTitle(navController: NavController) {

    var recipeTitle by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
    {
        Scaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),

            ) { values ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(end = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
            )
            {

                Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                    IconButton(onClick = { navController.currentBackStack }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                }
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(values)
                        .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 8.dp)
                        .weight(1f)
                )
                {
                    Text(
                        text = "What's Your Recipe Title?",
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        style = Typography.displaySmall
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))

                    Text(
                        text = "Keep the Title Short and Precise",
                        style = Typography.titleLarge
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))

                    TextFieldWithText(
                        "",
                        "e.g. Hamburger",
                        KeyboardType.Text,
                        recipeTitle
                    )


                }
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .weight(1f)
                        .padding(start = 8.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom
                ) {
                    OutlinedButton(
                        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                        onClick = { }
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Cancel")
                    }
                    Button(
                        onClick = {},
                        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Next")
                    }
                }

                Image(
                    painterResource(id = R.drawable.hamburger),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .wrapContentSize(unbounded = true, align = Alignment.TopEnd)
                )

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the current output:

[current output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVlgm.png)

In the screenshot I clarified the behavior that I want to implement:

[that line is actually a bell icon, it's on the left and only half of it is being shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K37Q4.png)

I've tried it with a burger image, but I actually need the bell icon

[the bell icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wswFx.png)

Comment: I think you can set the ```OffSet``` Of the ```Image``` You want to show to bottom right corner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Modifier.offset and LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.

Use this code and replace your Icon with Icons.Filled.DateRange.

```
Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
)
{
    Scaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            ) { values ->
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

            Image(
                    modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .fillMaxHeight(0.5f)
                            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                            .offset(x = (LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp / 2).dp),
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.DateRange,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
            )
            Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(end = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
            )
            {
                Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                    navController.currentBackStack
                    }) {
                        Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                                contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                }
                Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(values)
                                .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 8.dp)
                                .weight(1f)
                )
                {
                    Text(
                            text = "What's Your Recipe Title?",
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        style = Typography.displaySmall
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))

                    Text(
                            text = "Keep the Title Short and Precise",
                        style = Typography.titleLarge
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))

                TextFieldWithText(
                        "",
                        "e.g. Hamburger",
                        KeyboardType.Text,
                        recipeTitle
                )


                }

                Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(start = 8.dp),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom
                ) {
                    OutlinedButton(
                            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                            onClick = { }
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Cancel")
                    }
                    Button(
                            onClick = {},
                            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Next")
                    }
                }
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what i needed:)))